# Proof Verification: If 650 points in a circle of radius 16, prove that some 10 must lie in a ring of inner radius 2 and outer radius 3.

Tags: proof-verification, problem-solving

*If 650 points in a circle of radius 16, prove that some 10 must lie in a ring of inner radius 2 and outer radius 3.*

The area of any such ring is $5\pi$ and the area covered by the union of all rings is $19^2\pi = 361\pi$. On average, each ring will contain $650 * 5/361 \approx 9.002$ points. So there must be at least one ring with more than 9 points lying within.

Here I am using the Law of Large Numbers (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Law_of_large_numbers). If I repeatedly pick rings randomly from the infinite set of rings whose centers lie within the circle, the average number of points in each ring must approach 9.002.

Comment: What is "each ring"?

Comment: Any arbitrary ring we pick will contain 13 points on average.

Comment: Pick from which population of rings?

Comment: The set of all rings of inner radius 2 and outer radius 3 whose centers lie within the given circle of radius 16. Wait a sec...if the ring lies on the edge of the circle, part of it will lie within radius 19, so the total area I have to consider is not 256pi but 361pi, right? In that case the average number of points in each ring is a little above 9, which means one ring must hold 10 points.

Comment: If I see it right, the "correct" proof uses finitely many rings around the given points and shows the existence of a point with lots of overlapping - then the ring around this point contains the centres of the overlappers. On the other hand, you want to integrate over all rings with center in the disk. You must make the involved measures rigorous - which boils down to oing back to the other proof.

Comment: I understand. But what about my proof is not sufficiently rigorous? I am simply using the http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Law_of_large_numbers to show that as I pick hundreds and thousands and millions of arbitrary rings I am bound to find one with more than 9. I agree that the "correct" proof is more elegant, but I am here to learn what is specifically wrong about my proof.

Comment: This looks like a (slightly unorthodox) application of the (extended) pigeon hole principle

Comment: @vonbrand What is the extended pigeonhole principle are you talking about?